# Writing to the Response stream with MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, aspose

I'm saving a Word document to my MVC page (with Aspose.Words) using the response stream, but I'm getting a javascript alert of '200 OK' when returning my view, but nothing else changes.

Am I doing it correctly?

```
   wordDoc.Save(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response, "whatever", ContentDisposition.Inline, options);
   HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
   return View();
```

The Save method is documented [here](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsnet/Aspose.Words.Document.Save+Overload_5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to implement your own ActionResult which will accept `wordDoc` and render it to Response. It is more natural way of doing that kind of stuff in MVC.

Your ActionResult could look like that:

```
public class DocumentResult : ActionResult
{
  private readonly Document document;
  private readonly SaveOptions options;

  public DocumentResult(Document document, SaveOptions options)
  {
    this.document = document;
    this.options = options;
  }

  public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
  {
    this.document.Save(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response, "whatever", ContentDisposition.Inline, this.options);
  }
}
```

Then you can use it in your action:

```
return new DocumentResult(wordDoc, options);
```

Comment: The Save method only accepts a HttpResponse, not a HttpResponseBase - perhaps this is where I'm going wrong... System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response is accepted fine, but maybe it's not being used by the controller's context?

Comment: HttpResponseBase is mockable HttpResponse and there is class HttpResponseWrapper that wraps HttpResponse into HttpResponseBase (and MVC does that), so you can safely use HttpContext.Current.Response.